# Rails 3.1 - How to redirect properly with custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Pages model with field 'customURL'. I can do page#show at '/:customurl'. but because i've defined page show that way in routes, my create action now does a redirect on success to the wrong route. What should I change to most cleanly fix the redirect properly to point to '/:customurl' on save?

controller:

```
def create
  @page = Page.new(params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @page.save
      format.html { redirect_to page_url, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @page, status: :created, location: @page }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

routes:

```
resources :pages
...
get "/:customURL" => "pages#show"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `routes.rb`, you can add magic helpers.

```
get "/:customURL" => "pages#show", :as => :custom
```

Then in your controller

```
format.html { redirect_to custom_url(@page. customURL), notice: ... }
```

Now, "/:customURL" will need to be last in your `routes.rb`, routes are greedy, the first to match will get it. So if you have something like "/bob" and you have a controller listening at "/bob", the controller will get it before the pages controller.

Comment: Ok, hmmm this is crashing my server currently. I get this in the logs: `Exiting
.../config/routes.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `custom' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000001012054e8> (NameError)` let me know if there's a tweek i need here or if you possibly need more code... Do I need to add route helpers or something somewhere?

Comment: Ok, using what you have I was able to piece it together. This is what worked for me, maybe edit your answer accordingly?  In routes: `get "/:customURL" => "pages#show", :as => :pageshow` and in controller `format.html { redirect_to pageshow_path(@page.customURL),...`

Comment: Sorry, it's `as: :custom`. I'll fix that!

Comment: Can you add the other things i put in my comment? if you want to use custom in stead of 'pageshow' that's cool. In other words, just make it :as => and do @page.customURL? That worked for me anyways. thanks again.

Comment: Sure, `:as => :custom` is the same as `as: :custom` in newer ruby. Ruby added the JSON style (?) hash identifiers in addition to the hash-rocket (`=>`). However, I'm happy to adjust. Glad you got it working.