# How do I define a custom URL for a form confirmation page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, confirmation, custom-url

I am creating a basic product landing page with Rails in which users can enter their email address to be notified when the product launches. (Yes, there are services/gems etc that could do this for me, but I am new to programming and want to build it myself to learn rails.)

On successful submit of the form, I would like to redirect to a custom '/thanks' page in which I thank users for their interest in the product (and also encourage them to complete a short survey.)

Currently, successful submits are displayed at "/invites/:id/" eg "invites/3" which I do not want since it exposes the number of invites that have been submitted.  I would like to instead redirect all successful submits to a "/thanks" page.

I have attempted to research "rails custom URLs" but have not been able to find anything that works.  The closest I was able to find was this [Stackoverflow post on how to redirect with custom routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728304/rails-3-1-how-to-redirect-properly-with-custom-routes) but did not fully understand the solution being recommended.  I have also tried reading the [Rails Guide on Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but am new to this and did not see anything that I understood to allow for creating a custom URL.

I have placed my thanks message which I would like displayed on successful form submit in "views/invites/show.html.haml"

**My Routes file**

```rb
resources :invites
root :to => 'invites#new'
```

I tried inserting in routes.rb:

```rb
post "/:thanks" => "invites#show", :as => :thanks
```

But I don't know if this would work or how I would tell the controller to redirect to :thanks

**My controller** (basically vanilla rails, only relevant actions included here):

```rb
def show
    @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    show_path = "/thanks"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @invite }
    end
  end

# GET /invites/new
# GET /invites/new.json
def new
  @invite = Invite.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @invite }
  end
 end

 # POST /invites
 # POST /invites.json
 def create
   @invite = Invite.new(params[:invite])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @invite.save
       format.html { redirect_to @invite }
       #format.js { render :action => 'create_success' }
       format.json { render json: @invite, status: :created, location: @invite }
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       #format.js { render :action => 'create_fail' }
       format.json { render json: @invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

It would seem as if creating a standard URL for displaying a confirmation would be relatively straightforward.  Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to redirect after your create action, which is executed when the form is submitted.

Just add redirect_to in the following way:

```
def create
  @invite = Invite.new(params[:invite])

  if @invite.save
    ...
    redirect_to '/thanks'
  else
    ...
    redirect_to new_invite_path # if you want to return to the form submission page on error
  end
end
```

I omitted some of the code for brevity.

In your routes add:

```
get '/thanks', to: "invites#thanks"
```

Add the thanks action to your invites controller:

```
def thanks
  # something here if needed
end
```

And create a thanks.html.erb page in app/views/invites.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a route like this:

```
resources :invites do
  collection do
    get 'thanks'
  end
end
```

This will also create a path helper called `thanks_invites_path`.

It will be at the `invites/thanks` path, but if you want it to be on`/thanks`, you could just do as Jason mentioned:

`get "/thanks" => "invites#thanks", :as => :thanks`

The `as` part will generate a helper to access that page: `thanks_path`.

You would need a extra action in the controller called `thanks`, and put whatever info you need inside, and also you will need a additional view called `thanks.html.erb`

Since you want everybody to go to that page after a successful submit, in your create action you would have:

`format.html { redirect_to thanks_invites_path}` (or `thanks_path`), what ever you choose, when you name the route you can check it with `rake routes` if it's okay, and whatever `rake routes` says, just add `_path` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `get "/thanks" => "invites#thanks"` in `routes.rb` and then add this in your controller:

```
def thanks
end
```

Then add a file `app/views/invites/thanks.html.erb` with your thank-you content.